# min and max funcion to calculate minimum credit card balance

Tags: python, function, max, min

I am trying to write Python code using the minimum and maximum functions to calculacte miinimum balance on a credit card. it is calculated  like this:. The minimum payment is equal to either $10 or 2.1% of the customer's balance, whichever is greater; but if this exceeds the balance, then the minimum payment is the balance. Here is my code:

If the balance is 600
balance = 600
customerInterest = max((balance*0.021),10.00)
print(customerInterest)
If the balance is 11
balance = 11
customerInterest = min(max((balance * 0.021, 10.00)), balance)
print(customerInterest)

Comment: The question "can you help" is not desired here. You need to show some effort of your own, preferably including some attempted code, and a question that is much more specific. Please edit your question. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3 (with an example customer balance of $543.21):

```
from decimal import *

def calculateMinPayment(customerBalance: Decimal) -> Decimal:
    if not isinstance(customerBalance, Decimal):
        raise TypeError('unsupported parameter type for customerBalance')
    return min(max(Decimal('10'), customerBalance * Decimal('0.021')), customerBalance).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

print(calculateMinPayment(Decimal('543.21')))
```